# Strip html tags from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on redmine plugin(which restricts me from changing some methods), and i have array of words like following

```
["h1.", "Wiki", "\r\n", "qweqwe", "\r\n", "additional", "\r\n", "<br>", "\r\n", "<br>", "\r\n", "{{toc}}", "\r\n", "<br>", "\r\n", "<br>", "\r\n", "Hello", "World<br>", "\r\n", "<br>", "\r\n", "<br>"]
```

What i want to do is to strip all html tags, including new line symbols from this array, to only keep words. Is there any method that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built-in way to achieve this, but it’s easy to implement:

```
s = [...]
s.map { |e| 
  r = e.gsub(/\r|\n|<.*?>/, '').strip
  r.empty? ? nil : r 
}.compact
#⇒ => [
#  [0] "h1.",
#  [1] "Wiki",
#  [2] "qweqwe",
#  [3] "additional",
#  [4] "{{toc}}",
#  [5] "Hello",
#  [6] "World"
#]
```

Or, with `reject`:

```
s.map { |e| 
  e.gsub(/\r|\n|<.*?>/, '').strip
}.reject(&:empty?)
```

Of course, you are free to improve regexp’s pattern to remove whatever you want to remove.

Comment: There is in fact a built in way to do this, strip_tags, see answer from someone else. I'd use the built-in strip_tags, it's less likely to have bugs allowing XSS for odd input.

Answer (score 2):

Just include [`ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) and do the following:

```
x.map{ |item| strip_tags(item.squish) }.reject(&:empty?)
```

- `squish` removes the empty lines
- `sanitize` removes the tags
- `rejec(&:empty?)` removes empty strings